# Check value in when inside an pipe function

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

if `R.cond` resolve an not undefined value, should execute a `pipe` function **and pass the value** to the `pipe` function...

```
const publishClient = (resp, cb) => {
  console.log('Publishing ', resp);
  cb()
}

// Applying same process
const format = (letter) => ({'letter': letter});
const concact =  R.curry((num, letter) => num + '=' + letter);

// my method publish
const publish = partialRight(publishClient, [function() { console.log('Callback called!') }]);

// conditions to check
const condToRes = R.cond([
  [equals(1), concact('A')],
  [equals(2), concact('B')],
  [equals(3), concact('C')],
  [equals(4), concact('D')],
  [equals(5), concact('E')],
]);

// Publish only if condition resolves
// const resolveCond = when(condToRes, pipe(format, publish)) // NOT WORK,concact FN is ignored!
const resolveCond = pipe( // TRYING
  condToRes,
  when(HOW TO CHECK condToRes IS NOT NIL, pipe(format, publish))
);


// Call
resolveCond(1)

// SHOULD DISPLAY ..
Publishing 
{"letter":"A=1"}
Callback called!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test whether a value is `null` or `undefined` you can make use of `R.isNil`. When combined with the `R.complement` combinator, this will produce a function that evaluates to `true` when applied to a value that is *not* `null`/`undefined`.

This can be used to update your example to:

```
const resolveCond = pipe(
  condToRes,
  when(complement(isNil), pipe(format, publish))
);
```

Alternatively, `R.unless` can be used instead of `R.when`, which removes the need to wrap `R.isNil` with `R.complement`.

```
const resolveCond = pipe(
  condToRes,
  unless(isNil, pipe(format, publish))
);
```

Both approaches are equivalent, though `R.unless` perhaps reads a little better.